# How to input integer in c++ without using ">>"

Tags: c++, integer, cin, getline

**My Question/Problem:**
Right now my program is using `cin >>` to get input and thats working fine except for I need to use `getline()` at one point and I know I shouldn't mix things like `getline()` and `cin.get()` with `cin >>`. **How do I input an integer without using `>>`?**

**Research:**
I've tried to research this, but every result I find says to use `cin >>` [This is the closest I've found.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421965/using-cin-get-to-get-an-integer)

I would be just as happy to find a way to avoid using `getline()`.

Comment: Are you allowed to use `scanf` ?

Comment: I think so, but I've never heard of it. Let me Google...

Comment: It's quite possible to mix `cin >>` with `getline()` if you just [compensate for the newline problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10553849/597607).

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of ways:

- One way is to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the line into a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), and put that string into a [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) where you can use the input operator `>>`.
- Another way, if the input is only the number, is to use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to get the line, then convert it to a number using [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol).

Comment: The first option looks like what I'm looking for, but I'm confused about how to do it. Especially with using namespace std. This is what I've tried: `getline(cin,firstMiddleName);
  istringstream iss(firstMiddleName);
  iss >> firstMiddleName;`

Comment: @StarSweeper That looks fine, what problems do you have with it?

Comment: iss gives the error incomplete type not allowed. I've never used istringstream before, I'm sure I'm missing a line or something.

Comment: Yup. I needed #include <sstream> this works, thank you!

Comment: @StarSweeper Follow the link in my answer, it will tell you what header file you need.

Comment: This answer turned out not to work, but I'll leave it as accepted in case it works for someone else. Using @Bo Persson's  answer in the comments ended up working.

Comment: @StarSweeper If the answer doesn't solve your problem then you should not leave it as accepted. Remove it, it's okay. Just leave a comment about why for others.

Comment: This answer has the same issue as using mixing getline and >>, it skips the next input. This link has a good fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553597/cin-and-getline-skipping-input/10553849#10553849